# How do I secure the URL's of a Symfony Project in fosuserbundle?

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I am new to `Symfony2` and using `fosuserbundle`. 
I have created a small project using `fosuserbundle` which has a **registration, login, 2 forms consisting of radio buttons to choose and submit after logging in or registering and a logout**. 
The problem is that `after a person logs out` and `if he/she types in the url of the form say` [(link for the first form of the project)](http://example.com/InstituteProject/web/app_dev.php/eventsdayonedisplay) or  [(link for the second form of the project)](http://example.com/InstituteProject/web/app_dev.php/eventsdaytwodisplay) `then the forms display !!!!`. 
**I wanted to secure these links and show these links only if the user has logged in.**

```
    routing.yml

  InstituteProjectevents_student_homepage:
 path:     /hello/{name}
 defaults: { _controller: InstituteProject:Default:index }

 InstituteProjectevents_student_formpage:
 path: /form
 defaults: { _controller: InstituteProject:Default:form } 

 InstituteProjectevents_student_form:
 path: /forms
 defaults: { _controller: InstituteProject:Default:billboard }     

 InstituteProjectevents_student_eventsdayonedisplay:
 path: /eventsdayonedisplay
 defaults: { _controller: InstituteProject:Default:eventsdayonedisplay } 

 InstituteProjectevents_student_eventsdaytwodisplay:
 path: /eventsdaytwodisplay
 defaults: { _controller: InstituteProject:Default:eventsdaytwodisplay }  

 InstituteProjectevents_student_eventsregistered:
 path: /eventsregistered
 defaults: { _controller: InstituteProject:Default:eventsregistered }    

 fos_user_security_login:
 path: /login
 defaults: { _controller: InstituteProject:Security:login }

 fos_user_security_check:
 path: /login_check
 defaults: { _controller: InstituteProject:Security:check }

 fos_user_security_logout:
 path: /logout
 defaults: { _controller: InstituteProject:Security:logout } 

 fos_user_profile_show:
 path: /
 defaults: { _controller: InstituteProject:Profile:show }

 fos_user_profile_edit:
 path: /edit
 defaults: { _controller: InstituteProject:Profile:edit } 

 fos_user_registration_register:
 path: /
 defaults: { _controller: InstituteProject:Registration:register }

fos_user_registration_check_email:
path: /check-email
defaults: { _controller: InstituteProject:Registration:checkEmail }

fos_user_registration_confirm:
path: /confirm/{token}
defaults: { _controller: InstituteProject:Registration:confirm }

fos_user_registration_confirmed:
path: /confirmed
defaults: { _controller: InstituteProject:Registration:confirmed }

  Security.yml

# app/config/security.yml
security:
encoders:
    FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

providers:
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username

firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            default_target_path: /forms
        logout:       
          path: fos_user_security_logout
          target: fos_user_security_login
        anonymous:    true

access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }

   RegistrationController.php

 <?php

/*
 * This file is part of the FOSUserBundle package.
 *
 * (c) FriendsOfSymfony <http://friendsofsymfony.github.com/>
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
 * file that was distributed with this source code.
 */

namespace InstituteProjecteventsBundle\Controller;

use FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserEvents;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\FormEvent;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\GetResponseUserEvent;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\FilterUserResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface;

/**
 * Controller managing the registration
 *
 * @author Thibault Duplessis <thibault.duplessis@gmail.com>
 * @author Christophe Coevoet <stof@notk.org>
 */

class RegistrationController extends Controller
{
public function registerAction(Request $request)
{
    /** @var $formFactory \FOS\UserBundle\Form\Factory\FactoryInterface */
    $formFactory = $this->get('fos_user.registration.form.factory');
    /** @var $userManager \FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface */
    $userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');
    /** @var $dispatcher \Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface */
    $dispatcher = $this->get('event_dispatcher');

    $user = $userManager->createUser();
    $user->setEnabled(true);

    $event = new GetResponseUserEvent($user, $request);
    $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_INITIALIZE, $event);

    if (null !== $event->getResponse()) {
        return $event->getResponse();
    }

    $form = $formFactory->createForm();
    $form->setData($user);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $event = new FormEvent($form, $request);
        $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS, $event);

        $userManager->updateUser($user);

        if (null === $response = $event->getResponse()) {
            $url = $this->generateUrl('fos_user_registration_confirmed');
            $response = new RedirectResponse($url);
        }

        $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_COMPLETED, new FilterUserResponseEvent($user, $request, $response));

        return $response;
    }

    return $this->render('FOSUserBundle:Registration:register.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}

/**
 * Tell the user to check his email provider
 */
public function checkEmailAction()
{
    $email = $this->get('session')->get('fos_user_send_confirmation_email/email');
    $this->get('session')->remove('fos_user_send_confirmation_email/email');
    $user = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager')->findUserByEmail($email);

    if (null === $user) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException(sprintf('The user with email "%s" does not exist', $email));
    }

    return $this->render('FOSUserBundle:Registration:checkEmail.html.twig', array(
        'user' => $user,
    ));
}

/**
 * Receive the confirmation token from user email provider, login the user
 */
public function confirmAction(Request $request, $token)
{
    /** @var $userManager \FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface */
    $userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');

    $user = $userManager->findUserByConfirmationToken($token);

    if (null === $user) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException(sprintf('The user with confirmation token "%s" does not exist', $token));
    }

    /** @var $dispatcher \Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface */
    $dispatcher = $this->get('event_dispatcher');

    $user->setConfirmationToken(null);
    $user->setEnabled(true);

    $event = new GetResponseUserEvent($user, $request);
    $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_CONFIRM, $event);

    $userManager->updateUser($user);

    if (null === $response = $event->getResponse()) {
        $url = $this->generateUrl('fos_user_registration_confirmed');
        $response = new RedirectResponse($url);
    }

    $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_CONFIRMED, new FilterUserResponseEvent($user, $request, $response));

    return $response;
}

/**
 * Tell the user his account is now confirmed
 */
public function confirmedAction()
{
    $user = $this->getUser();
    if (!is_object($user) || !$user instanceof UserInterface) {
        throw new AccessDeniedException('This user does not have access to this section.');
    }

    //Get current time and date

    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Paris');
    $current_date = date('Y/m/d h:i:s a', time());

    //Set expiration date

    $deadline1 = $this->container->getParameter('deadline_day1');
    $date = date_create($deadline1, timezone_open("Europe/Paris"));

    if ($current_date > date_format($date, "Y/m/d h:i:s a")) {
        return $this->render('InstituteProject:Default:registrationsclosed.html.twig');
    }
    return $this->render('InstituteProject:Default:confirmed.html.twig', array(
        'user' => $user,
    ));
}
}
```

Comment: Thank You Abhishek Chaubey for editing the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add those two paths in `security.yml` files `access_control` section as follows,

Go through [This Documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html) to learn more about how it works in Symfony2

`ROLE_ADMIN` or `ROLE_USER` in ACL means you need to be logged in to access that path.

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/eventsdayonedisplay, role: ROLE_ADMIN }  # you can change user role to ROLE_USER as per your requirement
    - { path: ^/eventsdaytwodisplay, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

I will also suggest that you can add routes as  `/events/day1` or `/events/day2`

this way you need to add only one entry in your `access_control` like,

```
- { path: ^/events/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Comment: Thank You Straw Hat for the help, it worked. I don't have enough "reputation" in my stackoverflow.com account as I have joined newly, else I would have upvoted your answer. Thank You